# Cardview is not setted fully under the nav drawer menu toggle icon

Tags: java, android, android-studio

This is the by default coded `navigation drawer activity` and i can't find the `actionbardrawertoggle` code . I implemented the search `cardview` over the `appbar` and under `drawertoggle` icon But, the `cardview` is not settled fully over the app bar under `navdrawer` icon.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/282Rm.png)

Answer (score 0):

Adding a search view is actually very easy in Android as it has inbuilt support for it. Go through the Search view functionality provided by android for more details.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html